# How to reverse tuples in each row of a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, loops, tuples

I have a long text file, but here is the shortened version of tuples in my list.

```
[[(2, 4, 4)], [(5, 3, 3)], [(6, 2, 9)],
 [(3, 5, 7)], [(4, 9, 10)], [(8, 10, 3)],
 [(2, 5, 6)], [(6, 7, 2)], [(8, 5, 4)]]
```

Here is my code, using reverse()

```
for i in range(len(image_2dlist)):
    image_2dlist.reverse()

print(image_2dlist)
```

Which prints

```
[[(8, 5, 4)], [(6, 7, 2)], [(2, 5, 6)],
 [(8, 10, 3)], [(4, 9, 10)], [(3, 5, 7)],
 [(6, 2, 9)], [(5, 3, 3)], [(2, 4, 4)]]
```

But I need it to look like this

```
[[(6, 2, 9)], [(5, 3, 3)], [(2, 4, 4)],
 [(8, 10, 3)], [(4, 9, 10)], [(3, 5, 7)],
 [(8, 5, 4)], [(6, 7, 2)], [(2, 5, 6)]]
```

Comment: You do not have 'rows' in your original list. It can be written as `[[(2, 4, 4)], [(5, 3, 3)], [(6, 2, 9)],[(3, 5, 7)], [(4, 9, 10)], [(8, 10, 3)],[(2, 5, 6)], [(6, 7, 2)], [(8, 5, 4)]]`. What is a "row"? Do you want to reverse the values and order of every three tuples?

Comment: The first row starts with (2, 4, 4) and the second row starts with (3, 5, 7) etc.@DYZ

Comment: Why? What makes those positions special? What is 'etc.'? (There are infinitely many ways to interpret it)

Comment: I want to keep the values in the tuples the same, but reverse the index in the row.@DYZ

Comment: How do we know what is a row? You have a list of 9 lists of tuples. Is it 3 rows? 9 rows? 1 row? Unless your give a definition of a row, your problem cannot be solved.

Comment: Yes it is a 3row x 3column grid @DYZ

Answer (score 2):

```
L = [[(2, 4, 4)], [(5, 3, 3)], [(6, 2, 9)],
    [(3, 5, 7)], [(4, 9, 10)], [(8, 10, 3)],
    [(2, 5, 6)], [(6, 7, 2)], [(8, 5, 4)]]

In [28]: list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([L[i:i+3][::-1] for i in range(0, len(L), 3)]))
Out[28]: 
[[(6, 2, 9)],
 [(5, 3, 3)],
 [(2, 4, 4)],
 [(8, 10, 3)],
 [(4, 9, 10)],
 [(3, 5, 7)],
 [(8, 5, 4)],
 [(6, 7, 2)],
 [(2, 5, 6)]]
```

Comment: @HannaJones Formatting is irrelevant in a list. The list's internal representation has no format associated with it. After constructing the list, you could print it out in any format you choose (eg: `for i in range(0, len(L), 3): print(L[i:i+3])`

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[[(2, 4, 4)], [(5, 3, 3)], [(6, 2, 9)],
 [(3, 5, 7)], [(4, 9, 10)], [(8, 10, 3)],
 [(2, 5, 6)], [(6, 7, 2)], [(8, 5, 4)]]  

'''Initialize the 2d list of dimention 3x3'''
 b = [[None for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)]
 k,j=0,0

'''convert a-1d list to b-2d list'''
for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            b[i][j]=a[k]
            k=k+1

'''swap 0th and 2nd element'''   
for i in range(3):
        b[i][0],b[i][2]=b[i][2],b[i][0]

'''convert b-2d list to a-1d list'''
 for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            a[k]=b[i][j]
            k=k+1
print a
```

output:

```
 [[(6, 2, 9)], [(5, 3, 3)], [(2, 4, 4)], [(8, 10, 3)], [(4, 9, 10)], [(3, 5, 7)], [(8, 5, 4)], [(6, 7, 2)], [(2, 5, 6)]]
```

Comment: Please explain how the code works, and next time please format you code.

Answer (score 0):

```
ll = [  [(2, 4, 4)], [(5, 3, 3)], [(6, 2, 9)],
         [(3, 5, 7)], [(4, 9, 10)], [(8, 10, 3)],
         [(2, 5, 6)], [(6, 7, 2)], [(8, 5, 4)]
     ]
```

**Stage1**

```
start , end , step = 0 , 3, 3 
while end <= len(ll):
  print('Start:',start,'End :',end,'Step:',step)
  print(ll[start:end])
  start = start + step
  end = end + step
```

--

```
#Start: 0 End : 3 Step: 3
# [[(2, 4, 4)], [(5, 3, 3)], [(6, 2, 9)]]
#Start: 3 End : 6 Step: 3
#[[(3, 5, 7)], [(4, 9, 10)], [(8, 10, 3)]]
#Start: 6 End : 9 Step: 3
#[[(2, 5, 6)], [(6, 7, 2)], [(8, 5, 4)]]
```

**Stage2**

```
start , end , step = 0 , 3, 3 
while end <= len(ll):
  print(sorted(ll[start:end] ,reverse=True , key=lambda lt : lt[0][0]))
  start = start + step
  end = end + step
```

**--**

```
# sorted(ll[start:end]) =>  [[(2, 4, 4)], [(5, 3, 3)], [(6, 2, 9)]]
# lt = [(2, 4, 4)]
# lt[0] = (2, 4, 4) 
# lt[0][0] = 2
```

**Stage3**

```
start , end , step = 0 , 3, 3 
while end <= len(ll):
  out = sorted(ll[start:end] ,reverse=True , key=lambda lt : lt[0][0])
  for item in out:
    resultList.append(item)
  start = start + step
  end = end + step
```

**Printing The Result**

```
start , end , step = 0 , 3, 3 
while end <= len(resultList):
  print(resultList[start:end])
  start = start + step
  end = end + step
```

**RESULT**

```
[[(6, 2, 9)], [(5, 3, 3)], [(2, 4, 4)], 
  [(8, 10, 3)], [(4, 9, 10)], [(3, 5, 7)], 
   [(8, 5, 4)], [(6, 7, 2)], [(2, 5, 6)]]
```